# SQL Query for compiling Post metadata

Tags: sql, database, wordpress

I am working on wordpress and I need to generate timely csv files for the client, this has to include basic information about post from wp_posts like title, time & author. In Addition to this, I am using custom fields to store post_count, author name, author_email and few more meta fields.

**Structure of wp_postmeta**
id, meta_key, meta_value

**Structure of wp_posts**
id, title, date

wp_posts & wp_postmeta has 1:N relation.

If I do a simple innerjoin with statement

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta where wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id
```

then I get a row for each meta value, but what I want is each meta value to become a column and only one row per post.

How to write this query?

Please assume this to be a standard wordpress database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) if you are running MySQL:

```
SELECT wp_posts.*, GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta USING post_id
GROUP BY wp_posts.post_id;
```

Comment: Thank you, I haven't used the GROUP_CONCAT command before, will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but it popped up in my search. I used GROUP_CONCAT with key/value pairs as in:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(pm.meta_key, '=', pm.meta_value ORDER BY pm.meta_key DESC SEPARATOR ',') as meta
```